# How to get the supported 802.11 operation modes for a WLAN adapter in user mode?

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, wifi

I'm working on a packet capture software on Windows which supports to capture raw 802.11 packets on monitor mode. One thing I need to do is to get the **supported 802.11 operation modes for a WLAN adapter**.

I know how to do this in a kernel mode: just query the OID [OID_DOT11_OPERATION_MODE_CAPABILITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in a kernel driver.

However, I also want to know how to do this in user mode (a DLL). I already know that Microsoft has provided the [Native Wifi API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx). I can use the functions like **WlanQueryInterface**, **WlanSetInterface** to get/set the current operation mode (the code below shows it). But it doesn't provide a function to get the operation modes supported by the adapter.

Is there any way to solve this without relying on the kernel code? Thanks!

```
DWORD SetInterface(WLAN_INTF_OPCODE opcode, PVOID pData, GUID* InterfaceGuid)
{
    TRACE_ENTER();

    DWORD dwResult = 0;
    HANDLE hClient = NULL;
    DWORD dwCurVersion = 0;

    if (!initWlanFunctions())
    {
        TRACE_PRINT("SetInterface failed, initWlanFunctions error");
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    // Open Handle for the set operation
    dwResult = My_WlanOpenHandle(WLAN_CLIENT_VERSION_VISTA, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_PRINT1("SetInterface failed, My_WlanOpenHandle error, errCode = %x", dwResult);
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return dwResult;
    }
    dwResult = My_WlanSetInterface(hClient, InterfaceGuid, opcode, sizeof(ULONG), pData, NULL);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_PRINT1("SetInterface failed, My_WlanSetInterface error, errCode = %x", dwResult);
    }
    My_WlanCloseHandle(hClient, NULL);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return dwResult;
}

DWORD GetInterface(WLAN_INTF_OPCODE opcode, PVOID* ppData, GUID* InterfaceGuid)
{
    TRACE_ENTER();

    DWORD dwResult = 0;
    HANDLE hClient = NULL;
    DWORD dwCurVersion = 0;
    DWORD outsize = 0;
    WLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE opCode = wlan_opcode_value_type_invalid;

    if (!initWlanFunctions())
    {
        TRACE_PRINT("SetInterface failed, initWlanFunctions error");
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    // Open Handle for the set operation
    dwResult = My_WlanOpenHandle(WLAN_CLIENT_VERSION_VISTA, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_PRINT1("GetInterface failed, My_WlanOpenHandle error, errCode = %x", dwResult);
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return dwResult;
    }
    dwResult = My_WlanQueryInterface(hClient, InterfaceGuid, opcode, NULL, &outsize, ppData, &opCode);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_PRINT1("GetInterface failed, My_WlanQueryInterface error, errCode = %x", dwResult);
    }
    My_WlanCloseHandle(hClient, NULL);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return dwResult;
}
```